# Class object sharing across C# and Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, oop, dll

I create a lot of object classes when I do programming. There are many situations where same object definition will be reused across multiple projects. In windows, I simply build them into .dll file library and include them as the project reference. Therefore, when I need to add additional properties or methods, I just need to do it once and I don't need to worry about go through all projects and manually update the object class definition.

Now, I'm given a project to build an Android application which requires several object classes that's being used within other projects (and must be synced). Of course, I can manually create them within Android and update them every time whenever there's a change, but this is very dangerous because one day in the future, it is very likely to be out-of-synced.

Anyone have suggestions on how to share class library across C# and Android?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I know how to do this is to use [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/platform) which would allow you to write your entire Android application in C#.

The problem is Android and .Net use completely different runtimes that are not compatible.

Comment: I forgot to tag this answer as accepted. We end up going with Xamarin so we can reuse the C#.net library reference. Of course, they are not 100% compatible, but good enough for what we do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear enough view of what your application does, but if you are using the C# objects on a webAPI and looking to keep your objects synced with the client app, you can use Breeze.js - this keeps your client/server biz objects synced. The classes get pulled in dynamically via a meta service call.